# Java Class Definitions

Tags: java

Is there a difference in b/w class inheritance and nesting.
Or are they both the same ?

We can access super class variable by super keyword 
How to access innerclass variable?

```
class Outerclass
{
  static int c;
  int d=5;
  static class Inner
  {
    int a =9;
  }
  class NestedInner
  {
    int b=10;
  }
}

class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Outerclass Oc=new Outerclass();
    Outerclass.Inner n=Oc.new Inner();
    System.out.println("....a is...."+n.a);
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Inheritance and nesting are totally different in terms of meaning as well as usage. I suggest you google it out and find for  yourself.

Just for your reference, walk through these Oracle Documentation trails for

[Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

[Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Nested inner class can be used only inside the parent class thats defined. Where as inheritance is usedto extend an existing behaviour of the class.